# Getting InnerHTML from multiple elements and placing each text node into a new list item

Tags: javascript

So what I am trying to do is create a code that automatically adds a list item to the main list with information from a different list. You will see what I mean when you look at the code.

The problem I am having is that I can't seem to get the innerHTML of each element and then send them back to the other list as separate nodes in a new list item element. So far the code will only add the first list item and that is it.

I am trying to avoid using JQuery right now because I haven't learned it yet and I want to get the hang of vanilla JS first.

If you know the answer, if you could also just give a brief explanation on why the code works and what I was doing wrong. that would be great.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/uxswm7jq/

Here is the current JS.

```
window.onload = AutomatedListItemAddition();


// This is my first attempt at Automating Adding a new list item to the 
function AutomatedListItemAddition () {
let theStoneList = document.getElementById("the-list");
//create new li element
let newStoneListItem = document.createElement("li");
let newStoneListItemA = document.createElement("a");
//import new text node
let stoneName = document.querySelector('.TestItem').innerHTML;


let stoneId = document.querySelector('.TestItem');
    newStoneAttribute = stoneId.getAttribute("href");

//add text node to li element
newStoneListItemA.appendChild(document.createTextNode(stoneName));

 // Adding Attribute for Class
newStoneListItem.classList.add("filterDiv");
newStoneListItem.classList.add("show");
newStoneListItemA.href = newStoneAttribute;


// To pull the information for the Anchor tag into a List Item
newStoneListItem.appendChild(newStoneListItemA)

//add new list element built in previous steps to unordered list
//called numberList
theStoneList.appendChild(newStoneListItem);

}
```

Please refer to the JSFiddle link for the list contents and testing.

Comment: frankly i would learn jquery before generic javascript.  It's easier and therefore easier to learn.  The libraries such as jquery and react exist because vanilla js is missing some very useful features.
I am not a master of vanilla js but I think your problem is you're reading a property out of a collection (you select a class which always ends up as an array) and then read a property.  You'll only get one result, the first one.  You need to do an iteration on the result set.

Comment: actually your code has an error in it that you should have caught which would be your clue.  
document.querySelectorAll('.TestItem').innerHTML will completely fail because you're trying to get the innerhtml of the entire array, not an element in it.  This would work:  document.querySelectorAll('.TestItem')[0].innerHTML.  
Personally I hate foreach in java so I would query into a variable and then do a for loop based on the array length.

Comment: Thanks!  I am attempting it now but I am very new to JavaScript and coding in general. As of now, I am trying to query it correctly into a for loop but finding that the loop isn't getting the innerHTML from the array. Either that or i'm returning the information incorrectly. Are you able to show a example of how you'd do this?

Comment: did you see my second comment?  anyway something like this:  var data = document.querySelectorAll('.TestItem'); for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { newStoneListItem.appendChild( data[i]).innerHtml } ;   * don't know exactly what you're doing but you could possibly just add the entire array at once instead of one item at a time.